# Error : RangeError [MESSAGE_CONTENT_TYPE]: Message content must be a non-empty string

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to make a regular send command that takes the content from the slash command, but I get this error, I tried to fix it according to the previous answers that I received here, but, unfortunately, it doesn't work either.

```
RangeError [MESSAGE_CONTENT_TYPE]: Message content must be a non-empty string.
    at Function.verifyString (C:\Users\wiskj\Desktop\adminadminov\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\Util.js:416:41)
    at MessagePayload.makeContent (C:\Users\wiskj\Desktop\adminadminov\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessagePayload.js:114:22)
    at MessagePayload.resolveData (C:\Users\wiskj\Desktop\adminadminov\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessagePayload.js:129:26)
    at TextChannel.send (C:\Users\wiskj\Desktop\adminadminov\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\TextBasedChannel.js:171:61)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\wiskj\Desktop\adminadminov\commands\send.js:5:19)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\wiskj\Desktop\adminadminov\events\interactionCreate.js:13:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
```

**Code:**

```js
module.exports = async (bot, message, args, argsF) => {
    const {channel} = message;
    const content = Array.from(argsF).join(" ")
    await channel.send(content);
};
module.exports.names = ["send"];
module.exports.interaction = {
    name: 'send',
    description: 'Отправить сообщение от имени бота',
    options: [
        {
            name: "сообщение",
            description: "Укажите что хотите отправить",
            type: "STRING",
            required: true
        },
    ],
    defaultPermission: true
}, "962964961687138385";
        
module.exports.names = ['send'];
```

Comment: Have you checked the value of `content`?

Answer (score 0):

- As the error says, message content must be `non-empty-strings`.

```js
channel.send(`${content}`)
```

or

```js
channel.send(String(content))
```

- Either of these will work, since both are converting `content` into a [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String).